# Can I leave Vancouver airport, flying from Manila, with a Philippine passport, valid Canadian Visa, with connecting flight to Montreal?

Tags: transit, airports, vancouver, filipino-citizens, montreal

I have a **Philippine** passport with a **valid Canadian Visa** (multiple entry). I will be flying from Manila via Philippine Airlines to Vancouver and after a 5 hours will be on a **connecting flight to Montreal** via Air Canada.

Can I leave the airport and meet up with my sister who lives nearby (Richmond)?
If not, is there a place at the airport where both of us will be allowed to meet and have a meal together and talk?
Can my sister hand over to me winter clothes and other items that I will need to bring in Montreal?

Answer (score 5):

Vancouver-Montreal is a domestic flight. Thus, you will pass immigration as you arrive in Vancouver, after which you are inside Canada. You can then move within Canada however you want, you can even ditch your plane ticket and decide to walk to Montreal (not recommended).

As you don't want to live in fear of missing the connection, I suggest you meet your sister in the landside (publicly accessible) part of the airport. Remember to make sure you have enough free space in your hand luggage for all the winter clothes, as your bags are likely to be checked through from Manila.

Comment: Since you clear customs in Vancouver you will be required to collect your baggage and recheck it. Here is [the guide for Toronto](http://www.torontopearson.com/Connecting_from_usa.aspx#), and I'm pretty sure the same applies at other airports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advise. I was able to verify the process after Immigration and Customs thru the VYR website on their 'Navigating' tab.